# Parsing log to extract most common source IP & count in python

Tags: python, string, sys

This is my first question here on stack overflow and am eager to interact with many of you. I am sort of new at python and I am trying to write a python 3 script for extracting the most common source IP address and count from a log file.

**Here is an example of the log file:**

1;Jan 10, 2003 04:34:12.870401000 EST;65.240.185.205;2335;131.243.2.12;21;6;48;TCP;2335

2;Jan 10, 2003 04:34:12.870741000 EST;131.243.2.12;21;65.240.185.205;2335;6;48;TCP;21

3;Jan 10, 2003 04:34:13.050626000 EST;65.240.185.205;2335;131.243.2.12;21;6;40;TCP;2335

4;Jan 10, 2003 04:34:13.274193000 EST;131.243.2.12;21;65.240.185.205;2335;6;123;FTP;Response

5;Jan 10, 2003 04:34:13.455582000 EST;65.240.185.205;2335;131.243.2.12;21;6;56;FTP;Request

The result I am looking for is simple. Just a basic dictionary showing the IPs and the count. Preferably sorted.

**{65.240.185.205:3}**

**{131.243.2.12:2}**

Any suggestions regarding parsing this log file is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd just look for every log entry started with `<Number>;`, then split the entry anywhere ";" appears, to get a list of strings. For example, after splitting, the first entry would be a list: ["1", "Jan 10, 2003 04:34:12.870401000 EST", "65.240.185.205", etc.]. The third item in the list is the IP.

Comment: How do I split at the ";" ?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to do this, with variations on how to parse the individual log lines. In general, you should use a regular expression with the `re` standard library module, to parse the fields depending on how your logs get generated. With this, using `str.split` is a quick-and-dirty substitute. The `Counter` object from the `collections` standard library will count things for you.

```py
from collections import Counter

def getIP(line):
  parts = line.split(";")
  if len(parts) == 10:
    return parts[2]

with open("/path/to/log", "r") as f:
  ips = Counter(getIP(line) for line in f)
```

On your example, the value of `ips` is then below. The `Counter` object can be used just like a `dict`, so you can subscript, etc. If you want to sort things, there's a [HOWTO on sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) in the manual. Simplest would be to use `sorted()` with `ips.items()` and keying off the address or the count, depending on which you want to sort.

```
Counter({'65.240.185.205': 3, '131.243.2.12': 2})
```